# Possible to Create a folder in Hololens programatically

Tags: uwp, hololens

I have a UWP application that allows for multiple device installs at once and can send files to existing folders.

Is it possible to create a directory inside a folder that already exists?

When searching I came across a forum post that's five years old, https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/7793/is-it-at-all-possible-to-generate-a-directory-structure-on-the-hololens but not sure if it's now avaiable. In devicePortal I can't see any extension methods that allow for this.

Comment: Does the UWP application run on the PC? According to your post, it seems like there are multiple devices connected with your PC at the same time, and you want to manage files remotely at scale. Also, could you clarify the top-level directory where you want to create folders? For UWP app, there is some limit to access file system by default.

Comment: Running and connecting to multiple devices doesn't seem to be an issue, it'll iterate though and do it one at a time. Yes the application is running on a Windows 11 computer.
I'm trying to create a folder in the Documents directory on the hololens.

Comment: There isn't a documented Device Portal API to create a folder on the HoloLens remotely for now. As a workaround, you will need to develop a HoloLens app first for listening to PC app’s incoming request and create a folder with [CreateFolderAsync(String desiredName)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.createfolderasync?view=winrt-22000).

Comment: Ah okay, creating the folder manually isn't too big an imposition, thank you for your replies.